# (in cleanup) Can't call method "FETCH" on an undefined value Object/InsideOut.pm line 1953 during global destruction

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu-16.04

Original command:

```
nohup time -v --output=time_braker2_RNAonly.log braker.pl --species=BUSCO_BUSCO_sunbird_trimPLK_881882613 --useexisting --cores=40 --genome=/home/cch/sunbird/sunbird_RepeatMasker_trim/sunbird_platanus_trim_kraken_scaff_gapclosed_1000.fa.masked --softmasking 1 --hints=/home/cch/sunbird/sunbird_HISAT2_trim/sunbird_trim_hints_AS_400K.gff,/home/cch/sunbird/sunbird_HISAT2_trim/sunbird_trim_hints_China_400K.gff --UTR=off &
```

When I am running BRAKER2 I couldn't proceed and kept receiving this error messages repeatively in GeneMark-ET.stderr:

```
(in cleanup) Can't call method "FETCH" on an undefined value at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Object/InsideOut.pm line 1953 during global destruction
```

I have tried to update Object::InsideOut module but didn't do any help

This is line 1953 in the perl file:

```
head -n 1953 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Object/InsideOut.pm | tail -n 10
    return if (! $$self);

    # Grab any error coming into this routine
    my $err = $@;

    # Preserve other error variables
    local($!, $^E, $?);

    # Workaround for Perl's "in cleanup" bug
    if ($Config::Config{useithreads} &&
```

Another error message in getAnnoFastaJoingenes..stderr

```
usage: getAnnoFastaFromJoingenes.py [-h] -g GENOME -f GTF -o OUT
                                    [-t TRANSLATION_TABLE] [-s FILTER]
getAnnoFastaFromJoingenes.py: error: argument -o/--out: expected one argument
```

and this is my nohup file:

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at /opt/BRAKER/scripts/braker.pl line 7970.
ERROR in file /opt/BRAKER/scripts/braker.pl at line 7986
Failed to execute: perl /opt/Augustus/scripts/join_aug_pred.pl < /home/cch/sunbird/sunbird_BRAKER2_RNAonly_trim/braker/BUSCO_BUSCO_sunbird_trimPLK_881882613/augustus.tmp.gff > /home/cch/sunbird/sunbird_BRAKER2_RNAonly_trim/braker/BUSCO_BUSCO_sunbird_trimPLK_881882613/augustus.hints.gff
```

This is where my log file ends:

```
#Thu Dec 27 20:34:03 2018: Making a fasta file with protein sequences of /home/cch/sunbird/sunbird_BRAKER2_RNAonly_trim/braker/BUSCO_BUSCO_sunbird_trimPLK_881882613/augustus.hints.gtf
/usr/bin/python3 /opt/Augustus/scripts/getAnnoFastaFromJoingenes.py -g /home/cch/sunbird/sunbird_BRAKER2_RNAonly_trim/braker/BUSCO_BUSCO_sunbird_trimPLK_881882613/genome.fa -f /home/cch/sunbird/sunbird_BRAKER2_RNAonly_trim/braker/BUSCO_BUSCO_sunbird_trimPLK_881882613/augustus.hints.gtf -o 1> /home/cch/sunbird/sunbird_BRAKER2_RNAonly_trim/braker/BUSCO_BUSCO_sunbird_trimPLK_881882613/getAnnoFasta..stdout 2>/home/cch/sunbird/sunbird_BRAKER2_RNAonly_trim/braker/BUSCO_BUSCO_sunbird_trimPLK_881882613/errors/getAnnoFastaJoingenes..stderr
```

I have checked braker.pl line 7970:

```
head -n 7970 /opt/BRAKER/scripts/braker.pl | tail -n 10

sub get_anno_fasta {
    my $AUG_pred = shift;
    print LOG "\# "
        . (localtime)
        . ": Making a fasta file with protein sequences of $AUG_pred\n"
        if ($v > 2);
    my $name_base = $AUG_pred;
    $name_base = s/[^\.]+$//;
```

and braker.pl line 7986:

```
head -n 7986 /opt/BRAKER/scripts/braker.pl | tail -n 10

my $pythonCmdString = "";
if ($nice) {
    $pythonCmdString .= "nice ";
}
$pythonCmdString .= "$PYTHON3_PATH/python3 $string -g $genome -f $AUG_pred "
                 .  "-o $name_base 1> $outfile 2>$errorfile";

print LOG "$pythonCmdString\n\n" if ($v > 3);
system("$pythonCmdString") == 0
    or die("ERROR in file " . __FILE__ ." at line ". __LINE__
```

Really appreciate if anyone would have any idea on this, I have tried to see whether if there are any solution online but barely any sources and I have limited understanding of these...

Comment: Why the python tag?

Comment: This is mostly an inconsequential bug in Object::InsideOut. Perl tries to clean up the memory used by the objects and part of that memory has already been cleaned up. You can safely ignore that message.

Comment: Jens - sorry, accidental, thank you very much though

Comment: Corion - Than you very much for your explanation I'll try to solve the rest of the problems then!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the perl warning I found out the perl script from BRAKER2 downloaded at 22/12/2018 had a bug which has been fixed already in the latest version:

$name_base = s/[^.]+$// missing a ~ after =

```
$name_base =~ s/[^\.]+$//
```

check the latest version BRAKER.pl they have edit and added a lot of lines.